# Tesseract-OCR: need to train all types of samples?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I want to make an app that can convert printed business cards into text. I learned that tesseract-ocr can improve accuracy via training.

If I want high accuracy on each type of business card, do I need to train all types of business cards? There are hundreds types of business cards that have different fonts or format. Is there any other methods to achieve high accuracy in tesseract-ocr?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the standard English dictionary provided is quite strong. In most cases the first step to improve accuracy is pre-processing.

Imagemagick has a number of easy scripts you can use. The popular one I see around is http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/

Generally you want to achieve the following:

- Threshold the image
- Unsharp works well
- Remove noise (if image is good this may be covered by Adaptive Threshold)
- Ensure the tesseract whitelist suits the field it is reading

Hope this helps